# How to insert value in a xml files

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am using an xml files and whose content is like below

```
<Invoices>
   <Invoice>
      <Type>[Type]</Type>
      <Contact></contact>
   </Invoice>
<Invoices>
```

and in my class I want to fill the xml ontent with the data coming in the object
I want to replace [type] in `<Type>[Type]</Type>` with obj.type
how can I achieve this. Just want an idea.

This is my code:

```
foreach (XmlNode pnode in xmlParentNode)
{
    pnode.InnerText = objInvoice.Invoice_type;
    xmlRequestNode = pnode.SelectNodes("Contact");
    // var app = xdoc.Root.Descendants("Appliance").SingleOrDefault(e => (string)e.Element("Name") == applianceName);
    foreach (XmlNode item in xmlRequestNode)
    {
        if (item.Name == "ContactNumber")
        {
            item.InnerText = objInvoice.ContactNumber.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? It is not a complex task replacing some values or nodes in an XMLDocument or XDocument. So where are you facing a problem?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code. Where is ContactNumber in your your XML structure?  Is `xmlParentNode` a reference to the `<Invoices>` node or to `<Invoice>`?  Is there more than one `<Invoice>` in your XML or just one?

Comment: Seens the question has been changed here. And your code now has NOTHING to do with what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path);

foreach (XmlNode node in doc.GetElementsByTagName("Type[. = '[Type]']"))
    node.InnerText = "[Obj.Type]";

doc.Save(path);
```

Comment: thank you so much. and how can i insert value in many other nodes

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlString);

foreach (XmlNode typeNode in doc.SelectNodes("/Invoices/Invoice/Type[. = '[Type]']"))
{
    typeNode.InnerText= obj.type;
}

string modifiedXml = doc.OuterXml;
```

Comment: thank you so much. and how can i insert value in many other nodes

Comment: You can follow a similar approach to insert value in other nodes.  If you have a specific example of what you would like to do, please add it to the question.

Comment: i am doing something like this bt getting problem .

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: foreach (XmlNode pnode in xmlParentNode)
                    {   pnode.InnerText = objInvoice.Invoice_type;
                        xmlRequestNode = pnode.SelectNodes("Contact");
                       // var app = xdoc.Root.Descendants("Appliance").SingleOrDefault(e => (string)e.Element("Name") == applianceName);
                        foreach (XmlNode item in  xmlRequestNode)
                        {
                            if (item.Name == "ContactNumber")
                            {  item.InnerText = objInvoice.ContactNumber.ToString();
                            }